# Entropy method for Sidorenko's conjecture for paths of length 3

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, entropy, extremal-graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with vertex sets $X$ and $Y$ and edge
> density $\alpha$ (meaning that the number of edges is $\alpha|X||Y|$).
> Then $$\#\{(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)\in X^2\times Y^2: x_1y_1,\ x_2y_1,\
>  x_2y_2 \in E(G) \}\geq \alpha^3|X|^2|Y|^2.$$

This is the particular case of the famous [Sidorenko's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidorenko%27s_conjecture) for paths of length 3. Balazs Szegedy used the entropy method to prove all (then) known cases of Sidorenko's conjecture as well as few more. However, the general proof has a lot of abstract language. That is why Tim Gowers [provided](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2015/11/18/entropy-and-sidorenkos-conjecture-after-szegedy/) a more simpler proof for paths of length 3  stripping all the abstract language.

> The proof for paths of length 3 can be described as follows: *entropy*
> of a probability distribution $p:X\to [0,1]$ on a finite set $X$ is
> $\sum\limits_{x\in X}p(x)\log_2\frac{1}{p(x)}$. This is maximized for
> the uniform distribution, when it takes the value $\log_2|X|$. It
> follows that one way of proving that $|X|\geq m$ is to identify a
> probability distribution $p$ on $X$ with entropy greater than
> $\log_2m$. If $G$ is a bipartite graph with vertex sets $X$ and $Y$,
> then there is a probability distribution on the set of quadruples
> $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$ of vertices of $G$ such that $x_1y_1,
>  x_2y_1,x_2y_2$ are all edges, that is not in general uniform and that
> has very nice properties.
>
> The distribution is easy to describe. You first pick an edge $x_1y_1$
> of $G$ uniformly at random (from all the edges of $G$). Having picked
> $x_1y_1$ then you pick $x_2$ uniformly at random from the neighbours
> of $y_1$, and having picked $x_2$ you pick $y_2$ uniformly at random
> from the neighbors of $x_2$. This guarantees that $x_1y_1x_2y_2$ is a
> path of length $3$ (possibly with repeated vertices, as we need for
> the statement of Sidorenko's conjecture).

My goal was to understand how the proof works in that case and after some deeps thoughts and hard work I was able to understand the idea of the proof but I have some unclear moments with the formal/rigorous proof.

1. Am I right that the sample space is $\Omega=\{(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)\in X^2\times Y^2: x_1y_1,\ x_2y_1,\ x_2y_2 \in E(G) \}$?
2. As far as I understand, the probability distribution is defined on $\Omega$?
3. Then he defines $X_1,X_2,Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be random variables that tell us where $x_1,x_2,y_1$ and $y_2$  are. Am I right that $X_1,X_2:\Omega\to X$ and $Y_1,Y_2:\Omega\to Y$ or not?
4. Intuitively I understand the distribution on $\Omega$ but how to write it formally? So it is some function $\mathbb{P}:\Omega\to [0,1]$ and how is $\mathbb{P}[\omega]$ defined for each individual $\omega\in \Omega$?

Answer (score 1):

Following along with the the description, $x_1y_1$ is chosen uniformly among edges with probability $1/e(G)$. Then neighbors $y_2$ of $x_1$ and $x_2$ of $y_1$ are chosen (implicitly independently of each other) with (conditional) probabilities $1/d(x_1)$ and $1/d(y_1)$ respectively. Hence $$ {\Bbb P}(\{(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)\}) = \bigl( e(G)\, d(x_1)\, d(y_1) \bigr)^{-1}. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! But I think you meant that $\mathbb{P}(\{(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)\})=\dfrac{1}{e(G)d(y_1)d(x_2)}$ because $x_2$ is a neighbour of $y_1$ and $y_2$ is a neigbor of $x_2$. Right?

Comment: You’re right; I read the construction incorrectly. I’ll fix the answer soon.

Comment: Excuse me but let me ask you a question: The probability which you wrote it works if $G$ is a bipartite graph with vertex sets $X$ and $Y$. However, this distribution can be implemented in the case of general graph $G$, right? I guess in this case the distribution should be taken as $\mathbb{P}(\{(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2)\})=\dfrac{1}{2e(G)d(y_1)d(x_2)}$. Is that correct?